# Struggling to join multiple tables correctly to receive correct data

Tags: mysql, database, join, mysql5

**The situation:**

I have MySQL 5. I am trying to produce a report of companies and some profit details.

- Each company has jobs that we do for them.
- Each job has pieces of work involved in that job.
- Each piece of work has a task type

**What I want to retrieve:**

- I want to know the total profit for each company from all jobs
- The total costs for each company from all jobs
- A total amount of time spent on all jobs for each company - separated by the work type

**companies table:**

- id
- name

**jobs table:**

- id
- company_id
- budget
- costs

**work table:**

- id
- job_id
- type_id
- start_time
- end_time

**types table:**

- id
- name
- hourly_rate

**Relationships:**

companies ---< jobs ---< work >--- types

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two can be found with this query:

```
select
  c.name as company_name,
  sum(hour(end_time) - hour(start_time)) * hourly_rate - sum(costs) as total_profit,
  sum(costs) as total_costs
from companies c
join jobs j on j.company_id = c.id
join work w on w.job_id = j.id
join types t on t.id = w.type_id
group by 1;
```

the last can be found with this query:

```
select
  c.name as company_name,
  t.name as work_type,
  sum(hour(end_time) - hour(start_time)) as total_hours
from companies c
join jobs j on j.company_id = c.id
join work w on w.job_id = j.id
join types t on t.id = w.type_id
group by 1, 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, couldn't have asked for more!

Comment: Just realised the second one works fine but the first one produces values for total_costs which are all way too high! Any ideas?